# «Не желающий» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, причастия

**Не желающий остановиться на привал путник.**
Как писать "не" — слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

[Желающий](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9) — это причастие (действ. наст. вр. от *желать*).
Путник (какой?) ***не желающий*** остановиться на привал — это причастный оборот (причастие + зависимые слова).

"Не" с причастиями, имеющими при себе зависимые слова, пишется раздельно.

> **Не желающий** остановиться водитель, стараясь уйти от преследующих его правоохранителей, неоднократно создавал аварийные ситуации, пытался сбросить патрульный автомобиль с дороги (из статьи).

Стоит отметить, что правило не распространяется на субстантивированные причастия (перешедшие в разряд существительных).

*Желающие могут идти со мной. **Нежелающие** могут идти в обход через скалы, встретимся на той стороне* (О. Верещагин. Не остаться одному); *В Армении придумали новую статью доходов бюджета: выплаты с **нежелающих** служить в армии* (название статьи).

[НЕ с причастиями](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/1179-prichastiyami-90747.html)